# protobuf3 serialize a java object to json , the object hava a int32 field and the value is 0

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

i have try serialize a java object to JSON , the object have a int32 field and the value is 0

in the JSON ,the int32 field lost.

how to avoid it when serialize objects.

proto file like

```
message Pm {
int32 point = 1;
string url = 2;
}
```

java

```
...
pm.setPoint(0);
...
System.out.println(JsonFormat.printer().print(pm)); //result: {} expect :{"point": 0}
...
pm.setPoint(1);
...
System.out.println(JsonFormat.printer().print(pm)); //{"point": 1}
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve] and describe specifically how/where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

i have found the answer.the default value should be ignore when convert to JSON.includingDefaultValueFields method should be include the default filed and value

`System.out.println(JsonFormat.printer().includingDefaultValueFields().print(pm));`